# How to set a negative number to infinity without using an if statement (or ternary)

Tags: performance, if-statement, opengl, glsl, ternary-operator

I have the following piece of code:

```
for(uint i=0; i<6; i++)
        coeffs[i] = coeffs[i] < 0 ? 1.f/0.f : coeffs[i];
```

Which checks an array with 6 elements and if it finds a negative entry it sets it to infinity and otherwise leaves the entry intact.

I need to do the same thing without using any if-statements

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do this without any conditionals? Is it just for the "cool" factor? If so, I'd suggest you write it out as a full if (and add braces!). Two-months-from-now-you will thank you :)

Comment: This smells like early or wishful optimization. If this code is really so perf sensitive, you might start by not converting the float to an int for the comparison.

Comment: Just write the simple `if` statement, and let the compiler take care of the optimization. Then take a look at the assembly code. You'll likely find that the code was implemented with a conditional move, which is to say that it's implemented without branching.

Comment: I messed up with the tags, the reason I am doing this is because this code is in GLSL shaders, if statements (for what I am doing) will be innefficient. I cannot use the std infinity value for obvious reasons, and I cannot elt the compiler optimize my code as the if/statement in itself is not optimal.

Comment: Is it possible to use a very high non-infinite value, instead of infinity? Infinity doesn't play nice with the (other) operators

Comment: @Kninnug yes that is a possibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Big disclaimer up front: I haven't actually tested this, but I doubt it really is faster than using ternaries. Perform benchmarks to see if it really is an optimization!**

Also: these are implemented/tested in C. They should be easily portable to GLSL, but you may need explicit type-conversions, which may make them (even) slower.

There are two ways to do it, based on whether you strictly need `INFINITY` or can just use a large value. Neither use branching expressions or statements, but they do involve a comparison. Both use the fact that comparison operators in C always return either `0` or `1`.

The `INFINITY`-based way uses a 2-element array and has the comparison output choose the element of the choice-array:

```
float chooseCoefs[2] = {0.f, INFINITY}; /* initialize choice-array */
for(uint i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    int neg = coefs[i] < 0; /* outputs 1 or 0 */
    /* set 0-element of choice-array to regular value */
    chooseCoefs[0] = coefs[i]; 
    /* if neg == 0: pick coefs[i], else neg == 1: pick INFINITY */
    coefs[i] = chooseCoefs[neg]; 
}
```

If you can use a normal (but big) value instead of `INFINITY` you can two multiplications & one addition instead:

```
#define BIGFLOAT 1000.f /* a swimming sasquatch... */
for(uint i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    int neg = coefs[i] < 0;
    /* if neg == 1: 1 * BIGFLOAT + 0 * coefs[i] == BIGFLOAT,
     else neg == 0: 0 * BIGFLOAT + 1 * coefs[i] == coefs[i] */
    coefs[i] = neg * BIGFLOAT + !neg * coefs[i];
}
```

Again, I didn't benchmark these, but my guess is that at least the array-based solution is far slower than simple ternaries. Don't underestimate the optimizing-power of your compiler!

Comment: The compiler is wothless for GPU computing, as what makes if statements slow is the way teh hardware actually executes the code. it's at the hardware level so the compiler can't do anything

Comment: Yes but what makes branching innefficient is not the assmebly code, is the execution hardware on the GPU which associates a single program counter to multiple cores, the compiler cannot optimize hadware

Comment: Sure, but the (GLSL) compiler may be better at optimizing a ternary operator than the tricks I proposed. The GPU instruction set may have for example conditional move instructions that are faster than these tricks, but the compiler is less likely to emit them from this code. Without benchmarks you can't say what is and isn't efficient. If your current code is fast enough, you should leave it as-is for clarity.

Comment: No you don't understand, when you are computing something in the GPU with GLSL, your code is implicitly paralellized. However it is parallelized in such a way that the same program counter is shared for all threads. this means that if there are 1000 threads of which 500 run one version of the branch and the other 500 run the other, the cores can only execute 500 threads at a time instead of 1000 (you've lost 50% of your computing power already). For each time this happens you keep dividing until the worst case scenario has you running one thread on 1000 cores.

Comment: @Makogan: "*this means that if there are 1000 threads of which 500 run one version of the branch and the other 500 run the other, the cores can only execute 500 threads at a time instead of 1000 (you've lost 50% of your computing power already).*" Nonsense. This assumes that the compiler is incapable of generating branchless code from source code that executes a branch. ?: operators, even on completely arbitrary branches, are about the easiest thing for compilers to optimize in such a way that they execute the same code across *all* invocations in a wavefront.

Comment: @Makogan: Or to put it another way, your question proceeds from a false assumption.

Comment: So ternary's can be optimized in such a way that they result in branchless execution?

Comment: @Makogan: A full-fledged `if` statement can be optimized to produce branchless execution. It all depends on the circumstances. That's why benchmarking these kinds of things is so paramount. Start with working code, then make it faster; don't try to make your code look odd before you know that you need to.

Comment: @Makogan: There is no GPU architecture out there with subgroup/warp/wavefront sizes above 64 threads. Even if you diverge on a single branch like that, it means that both branches are executed after each other, with some cores masked out during each branch, and the control flow becomes uniform again after that. If you replace two divergent code pieces with just very simple ops by some uniform control flow block with more complex operations, you are actually _decreasing_ performance.

Comment: @Makogan: I'm pretty sure most GPUs have conditional-move instructions that let them compare and then select one of two inputs.  i.e. an GPU asm instruction which implements a ternary operator.  Use a ternary operator in your source so the compiler can use it efficiently.  Just like compiling for x86, a compiler can use cmp / cmovle  to implement `(a<b) ? c : d;`

Answer (score 2):

One obvious question would be *what* infinity you need when the input is less than 0.

#### Any Infinity

If the result can be negative infinity, I'd do something like this:

```
coeffs[i] /= (coeffs[i] >= 0.0);
```

The `coeffs[i] >= 0.0` produces 1.0 if the input is positive, and `0.0` if the input is negative. Dividing the input by 1.0 leaves it unchanged. Dividing it by 0 produces infinity.

#### Positive Infinity

If it has to be a positive infinity, you'd change that to something like:

```
coeffs[i] = (fabs(coeffs[i]) / (coeffs[i] >= 0.0);
```

By taking the absolute value before the division, the infinity we produce for a negative is forced to be positive. Otherwise, the input started out positive, so the `fabs` and division by 1.0 leave the value intact.

#### Performance

As to whether this will actually improve performance, that's probably open to a lot more question. For the moment, let's look at code for the CPU, since Godbolt lets us examine that pretty easily.

If we look at this:

```
#include <limits>

double f(double in) {
    return in / (in >= 0.0);
}

double g(double in) { 
    return in > 0.0 ? in : std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
}
```

So, let's look at the code produced for the first function:

```
  xorpd xmm1, xmm1
  cmplesd xmm1, xmm0
  movsd xmm2, qword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_0] # xmm2 = mem[0],zero
  andpd xmm2, xmm1
  divsd xmm0, xmm2
  ret
```

So that's not too terrible--branch-free, and (depending on the exact processor involved) a throughput *around* 8-10 cycles on most reasonably modern processors. On the other hand, here's the code produced for the second function:

```
  xorpd xmm1, xmm1
  cmpltsd xmm1, xmm0
  andpd xmm0, xmm1
  movsd xmm2, qword ptr [rip + .LCPI1_0] # xmm2 = mem[0],zero
  andnpd xmm1, xmm2
  orpd xmm0, xmm1
  ret
```

This is also branch-free--and doesn't have that (relatively slow) divsd instruction either. Again, performance will vary depending on the specific processor, but we can probably plan on this having a throughput around 6 cycles or so--not *tremendously* faster than the previous, but probably at least a few cycles faster part of the time, and almost certain to never be any slower. In short, it's probably preferable under nearly any possible CPU.

#### GPU Code

GPUs have their own instruction sets, of course--but given the penalty they suffer for branches, compilers for them (and the instruction sets they provide) probably do at least as much to help eliminate branches as CPUs do, so chances are that the straightforward code will work just fine on it as well (though to say with certainty, you'd need to either examine the code it produced or profile it).

Comment: I need positive infinity

Comment: Your best bet on x86 for throughput might be `cmpltpd xmm1, xmm0` / `andps xmm1, plus_infinity` / `maxpd xmm0, xmm1`.  For inputs >= 0, you'll do `max(x, 0.0) = x`.  For inputs less than 0 you'll do `max(x, +Inf) = +Inf`.  I don't think we can use the fact that all-ones = NaN to get any more efficient, because MAXSD / MAXPD.  On Haswell, `cmppd` and `maxpd` both run only on port 1 (on the FP-add unit I guess), so that's only one per 2 clocks, but SKL runs them on the FMA units on ports 0/1 (giving us 1 per clock throughput.)

Comment: Not sure how you got 6 cycle throughput for your blend version.  It's only 6 uops (and the load could be hoisted out of loops), and only 3 of them need port 5 on Intel pre-Skylake (the FP booleans).  Obviously it auto-vectorizes better than division, which has lower throughput for YMM vectors.  And with SSE4.1, it would use `blendvpd` instead of AND/ANDN/OR, which is only 2 uops, or 1 on Skylake (any port) for the non-VEX version.  With AVX for non-destructive, it's 2 or 3 uops per vector (vcmppd / vblendvpd).  If surrounding code doesn't need p5 too much, it's fantastic.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Oops--I think I meant to say something like "no worse than 6 clocks". I don't remember for sure, but I'd guess I counted uOps, which gave a rough upper bound on the time. Hardly seems worth working at getting a better number for only six iterations--seems to me the only real question is whether the data's already in the cache or not. Oh, and the real target is a GPU anyway, so we're only using the CPU as a proxy to get a general notion of whether a compiler can produce decent code from the obvious source--to which the answer is a clear "yes".

Comment: @PeterCordes: Summary: the compiler produces *really* good results from the obvious source code. The attempt at a "clever" approach produces results that are normally worse. And yeah, even though the compiler does really well, somebody who knows assembly language can still do significantly better.

Comment: The fun part is that you can turn that asm knowledge back into something that will compile efficiently :)  like maybe `double cmp = x<0 ? +Infinity : 0;  return max(x, cmp);`.  But for a GPU, yeah you're probably better with a straight ternary.  I'd assume they have FP cmov directly, because GPUs aren't like CPU short-vector SIMD where things are designed for blending based on compare vectors.

Comment: @PeterCordes: At least at first glance that doesn't look to me like it's giving an obvious improvement. https://godbolt.org/g/3kFRkd

Comment: Some of those `movapd` instructions could go away on inlining, and they don't need execution ports on IvB+ or Bulldozer/Ryzen (mov-elimination).  Looked like only 3 uops that need SIMD ALUs (xor-zeroing doesn't on Intel but does on AMD), so there's a potential win there vs. SSE2 AND/ANDN/OR blending.  Depends on port bottlenecks in surrounding code.  Thanks for checking it out on Godbolt, I was too lazy :P  In all the versions, the load can be hoisted, but the XOR-zeroed reg needs to be re-materialized in the loop so cmpsd can clobber it (with AVX).

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yeah--at least right off, it looks like it would work out pretty close to what the normal ternary produced. With the extra moves gone, it basically comes down to the final instructions being and/or for the original, and and/max for the revised version. Unlikely to make a big difference either way.

Comment: BTW, part of the reason I commented is that compare/blend is way better than division.  Division *can* be cheap if there's a lot of surrounding code, but it still has high latency (more to hide for OoO execution).  I'd expect it's especially problematic for GPUs; Dividers are expensive, so for example Intel CPUs have a divider that's less wide than the SIMD FMA units.  Wouldn't be surprised if multiple GPU "cores" share a single divider or something, because replicating a divider for every core makes much less sense than replicating an FMA unit.  Compare/AND/DIV is just silly, IMO.